# Projection matrices(meaning)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is as follows :

Compute the projection matrices $$aa^T/a^Ta$$ for $$a_1=(-1,2,2) \\ a_2=(2,2,-1)$$

Multiply those projection matrices and explain their product P1P2 and what it is.

So we use the formula to find P1 and P2 pretty easily. I managed to find P1P2 there is no problem in that area, however I'm having bad time understanding the logic and meaning of P1P2

so I know that nullspace of P1 is perp to the collapse of a. But I don't know any other logic behind these projection matrices.

I tried thinking and I thought P1P2 would mean mutual orthogonal space to *a1 a2*? I don't know, If someone could help me out about this logic behind projection matrices I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: What did you get for the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just found out,

Since P1 projects onto a column space, and P2 projects onto the column space perp which is the left nullspace, and SİNCE  the whole space consists of two perpendicular spaces.

Once you project to the column space you get the vector $v_1$ and this $v_1$ won't project to the columnspace perp since projection something which is perp would produce the $0$ vector/matrix.

Just wanted to let you guys know.